# Delay closing of submenu on a css menu made exclusively with divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have made this horizontal menu with DIVs, (no ul and li lists used at all), i am looking for a way to delay the colapse of the submenus on mouse out, dont mind if it is with javascript, jquery or CSS.
i tried some javascript solutions but none worked.

the CSS

```
.topmenu
{
margin: 0 auto; width: auto;float:left; 
position:relative;
z-index:4;
height: 50px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:16px;
color:#444;
}

.topmenu a
{
padding:0 16px;
line-height:50px; /*Note: keep this value the same as the height of .topmenu */
font-size:16px;
font-weight:normal;
display:block;
outline:0;
text-decoration: none;
position:relative;
color:#444;
}

 .topmenu .home, .topmenu .button1, .topmenu .button2 {float: left;}
 .topmenu .home img {vertical-align: top; margin-top:8px; border:none;}
 .topmenu .home:hover a, .topmenu .button1:hover a, .topmenu .button2:hover a
  {background-color:#333; color:#FFF; z-index:9;}



 .topmenu .subhome,
 .topmenu .submenu1,
 .topmenu .submenu2
 {
position: absolute;
right:0;
z-index:20;
display:none;
background-color:#0e5079;           
text-align: left;
padding: 20px;  
top:50px;
color:#999;
border-radius:3px;
-moz-box-shadow:1px 2px 12px #333333;
-webkit-box-shadow:1px 2px 12px #333333;
box-shadow:1px 2px 12px #333333;
text-shadow:
-1px -1px 0 #333,0px -1px 0 #333,1px -1px 0 #333,-1px 1px 0 #333,0px 1px 0 #333,1px 1px 0 #333;
 }
.topmenu .home:hover .subhome {display:block;}
.topmenu .button1:hover .submenu1 {display:block;}
.topmenu .button2:hover .submenu2 {display:block;}

.topmenu .subhome {
width:960px;
height:560px;
background-image:url(menu/menu-bg/corfu-bw-bg.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;     
  }
.topmenu .submenu1 {
background-image:url(menu/menu-bg/benitses-bg.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;     
}
.topmenu .submenu2 {
background-image:url(menu/menu-bg/corfu-bg.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;     
}
.topmenu .submenuleft {padding:20px;float:left;}
.topmenu .submenuleft span {font-weight:bold; font-size:16px;color:#DDD;line-  height:32px;}
.topmenu .submenuleft a span {font-weight:bold; font-size:16px;color:#FA0;padding-   top:5px;padding-bottom:8px;}
.topmenu .submenuleft a span:hover {color:#FF0; text-decoration:none;}
.topmenu .submenuleft a:hover {color:#FF0;font-size:14px;text-decoration:none;background:none;}
.topmenu .submenuleft img {display:block;border:#FFF 2px solid;padding:4px;margin-top:5px;}

.topmenu .subhome .submenuleft a,
.topmenu .submenu1 .submenuleft a,
.topmenu .submenu2 .submenuleft a
{
padding:0px;
line-height:26px;
font-size:14px;
background:none;
display: inline;
text-align:left;    
z-index: 0;
}
```

and the HTML

```
     <div class="topmenu">
<div class="home"><a href="#">HOME</a>
     <div class="subhome">
     </div> 
</div>
<div class="button1"><a href="#">ITEM1</a>
    <div class="submenu1" style="width:840px;">
        <div class="submenuleft">
                <a href="#"><span>LINK TITLE</span></a><br> 
                <a href="#">Example link</a><br>
                <a href="#">Example link</a><br>
                <a href="#">Example link</a><br>
                <a href="#">Example link</a>
        </div>
        <div class="submenuleft">
                <a href="#"><span>LINK TITLE</span></a><br> 
                <a href="#">Example link</a><br>
                <a href="#">Example link</a>
        </div>
        <div class="submenuleft">
                <a href="#"><span>LINK TITLE</span></a><br> 
                <a href="#">Example link</a><br>
                <a href="#">Example link</a><br>
                <a href="#">Example link</a><br>
                <a href="#">Example link</a><br>
                <a href="#">Example link</a>
        </div>
        <div class="submenuleft" style="text-align:right;width:130px;">
            <img src="menu/benitses-m.jpg" alt="" style="width:128px; height:200px; height:190px;margin-top:5px;">
        </div>            
    </div>
</div>

<div class="button2"><a href="#">ITEM2</a>
     <div class="submenu2" style="width:800px;">
       <div class="submenuleft">
                 <a href="#"><span>LINK TITLE</span></a><br> 
                 <a href="#">Example link</a><br>
                 <a href="#">Example link</a><br>   
                 <a href="#">Example link</a>                  
        </div>
        <div class="submenuleft">
                 <a href="#"><span>LINK TITLE</span></a><br>                  
                 <a href="#"><span>LINK TITLE</span></a><br> 
                 <a href="#">Example link</a><br>
                 <a href="#">Example link</a>                  
        </div>
        <div class="submenuleft">
                  <a href="#">Example link</a><br>
                  <a href="#">Example link</a><br>
                  <a href="#">Example link</a>                   
        </div>
        <div class="submenuleft" style="text-align:right; width:140px;">
            <img src="menu/mouse-island.jpg" alt="" style="width:140px; height:210px;">
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

You can see a TEST example of this menu [here][1]

Thank you

[1]:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, using CSS Transitions. Just use `visibility` property to show and hidden the menu (instead of switching `display` between `block` and `none`), specifying the transition on it you'll delay the change from `visible` to `hidden` only, not the inverse.

Obviously you can also create a fade effect, animating the `opacity` property.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/KVtV7/

Sample code:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="">Text</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="">C</a></li>
            <li><a href="">D</a></li>
            <li><a href="">E</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#menu ul{
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    -moz-transition-property: visibility;
    -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-transition-property: visibility;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
    transition-property: visibility;
    transition-duration: 2s;
}

#menu li:hover > ul{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: Using this technique the hiding of the submenu will start as soon as the user hovers outside of it. If that is acceptable then this is a nice solution.

Comment: @koenp I don't get it, when should it start instead?

Comment: It depends on how you want the effect to take place. If I'm not mistaken using this technique the submenu will fade out over a period of 2 seconds. If you want to not fade out but to just disappear instantaneously 2 seconds after the user left the submenu with his mouse then this does not work.

Comment: @koenp No, it doesn't fade (but it can), it disappears instantaneously. Have you tried the live demo? Which browser are you using?

Comment: Ok, i tried and it worked as i prefered but it created another issue.

Comment: @user3127709 What's the issue?

Comment: submenu stays on for 2 secs, (there is no fade just instand colapse after 2 secs) and this is what i prefered, but it also creates another problem, when mouse jump to the next menu item both submenus are visible for 2 seconds, and this looks weird, i try to find a solution to this

Comment: @user3127709 Yeah, you're right. First, use `z-index` in order to show always on the top the currently hovered menu. To prevent the other menus to be visible, you could perfectly overlap them, set their position and sizes to be always the same. But I don't know if such solution is applicable in your case.
However, I think I answered to the original question, so don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: If the delay is shorter, ie 1 second which is enough and the effect was fade out for the previous button and fade in for the next, then everything will look smooth and nice, you see is impossible to make all subs the same size, Anyway i accept your answer and thank you, do i have to press something? you see iam new to this stackoverflow, just 1 hour member.

Comment: @user3127709 I'm glad you found a solution for you problem. To know how to accept an answer, give a look at the help center: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: That was to easy!! i found the best solution, pure CSS combination of visibility and opacity properties, see the result [here][1]


  [1]: http://atcorfu.com/test.html

it works on all modern browsers, looks awesome, Thanks to Carlo Cannas who pointed me to the right direction...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delay the hiding of an element (using :hover) with CSS only. The browser renders the new state instantly. You'll need some JavaScript and `setTimeout` magic to get this working.

A simple example would be something like the code below. I used jQuery here because it is compact and it provides some helpful stuff like the `mouseleave` event.

I added a class `button` to each button `div` .

```
<div class="button1 button"><a href="#">ITEM1</a>

$('.button').each(function() {

  // We use closures here so that each button has it's own 'to'.
  var $that = $(this)
      ,to;

  $that.on('mouseleave', function() {

    // We wait 500 ms using setTimeout
    to = setTimeout(function() { 
      $that.find('> div').hide(); 
    }, 500);
  });

  $that.on('mouseenter', function() {

    // Hide all other open submenu's that are potentially open.
    $('.button > div').hide(); 

    // I use a show here, but you could also keep using your CSS :hover technique. 
    // In that case remove this show call. 
    $that.show();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

the code with 3 main buttons(can be expanded to any number) can be like this, includes pictures and background images etc...

HTML

```
 <div class="topmenu">
<div class="home"><a href="#">HOME</a>
     <div class="subhome">
     </div> 
</div>
<div class="button1 sub"><a href="#">ITEM1</a>
    <div class="submenu1" style="width:840px;">
        <div class="submenuleft">
                <a href="#"><span>LINK TITLE</span></a><br> 
                <a href="#">Example link</a><br>
                <a href="#">Example link</a><br>
                <a href="#">Example link</a><br>
                <a href="#">Example link</a>
        </div>
        <div class="submenuleft">
                <a href="#"><span>LINK TITLE</span></a><br> 
                <a href="#">Example link</a><br>
                <a href="#">Example link</a>
        </div>
        <div class="submenuleft">
                <a href="#"><span>LINK TITLE</span></a><br> 
                <a href="#">Example link</a><br>
                <a href="#">Example link</a><br>
                <a href="#">Example link</a><br>
                <a href="#">Example link</a><br>
                <a href="#">Example link</a>
        </div>
        <div class="submenuleft" style="text-align:right;width:130px;">
            <img src="" alt="" style="width:128px; height:200px; height:190px;margin-top:5px;">
        </div>            
    </div>
</div>

<div class="button2"><a href="#">ITEM2</a>
     <div class="submenu2" style="width:800px;">
       <div class="submenuleft">
                 <a href="#"><span>LINK TITLE</span></a><br> 
                 <a href="#">Example link</a><br>
                 <a href="#">Example link</a><br>   
                 <a href="#">Example link</a>                  
        </div>
        <div class="submenuleft">
                 <a href="#"><span>LINK TITLE</span></a><br>                  
                 <a href="#"><span>LINK TITLE</span></a><br> 
                 <a href="#">Example link</a><br>
                 <a href="#">Example link</a>                  
        </div>
        <div class="submenuleft">
                  <a href="#">Example link</a><br>
                  <a href="#">Example link</a><br>
                  <a href="#">Example link</a>                   
        </div>
        <div class="submenuleft" style="text-align:right; width:140px;">
            <img src="" alt="" style="width:140px; height:210px;">
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS part

```
      .home .topmenu .home a,
      .button1 .topmenu .button1 a,
      .button2 .topmenu .button2 a { 
      color:#FFF;  
      background-color:#a4472d;
 }
.topmenu
{
      margin: 0 auto; width: auto;float:left; 
      position:relative;
      z-index:20;
      height: 50px;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:16px;
  color:#444;
    }

     .topmenu a
 {
     padding:0 16px;
     line-height:50px; /*Note: keep this value the same as the height of .topmenu */
     font-size:16px;
     font-weight:normal;
     display:block;
     outline:0;
     text-decoration: none;
     position:relative;
 color:#444;
 }

     .topmenu .home, .topmenu .button1, .topmenu .button2 {float: left;}
     .topmenu .home img {vertical-align: top; margin-top:8px; border:none;}
     .topmenu .home:hover a, .topmenu .button1:hover a, .topmenu .button2:hover a  {background-color:#333; color:#FFF; z-index:9;}



     .topmenu .subhome,
     .topmenu .submenu1,
     .topmenu .submenu2
{
    position: absolute;
right:0;
    z-index:20;
visibility:hidden; 
opacity:0;        **/* use both visibility and opacity */**
    background-color:#0e5079;           
    text-align: left;
    padding: 20px;  
    top:50px;
color:#999;
border-radius:3px;
-moz-box-shadow:1px 2px 12px #333333;
-webkit-box-shadow:1px 2px 12px #333333;
box-shadow:1px 2px 12px #333333;
text-shadow:
-1px -1px 0 #333,0px -1px 0 #333,1px -1px 0 #333,-1px 1px 0 #333,0px 1px 0 #333,1px 1px 0 #333;

    -moz-transition-property: visibility, opacity;
    -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-transition-property: visibility, opacity;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
    transition-property: visibility, opacity;
    transition-duration: 2s;   **/* some changes on transition */**

   }
   .topmenu .home:hover .subhome {visibility:visible; opacity:1; z-index:150;}
   .topmenu .button1:hover .submenu1 {visibility:visible; opacity:1; z-index:150;}
   .topmenu .button2:hover .submenu2 {visibility:visible; opacity:1; z-index:150;  **/* the rise of z-index during topbuttons hover is important */**}


.topmenu .subhome {
width:960px;
height:560px;
background-image:url(example.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;     
}
    .topmenu .submenu1 {
background-image:url(example2.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;     
}
    .topmenu .submenu2 {
background-image:url(example3.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;     
}
    .topmenu .submenuleft {padding:20px;float:left;}
    .topmenu .submenuleft span {font-weight:bold; font-size:16px;color:#DDD;line-height:32px;}
    .topmenu .submenuleft a span {font-weight:bold; font-size:16px;color:#FA0;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:8px;}
    .topmenu .submenuleft a span:hover {color:#FF0; text-decoration:none;}
    .topmenu .submenuleft a:hover {color:#FF0;font-size:14px;text-decoration:none;background:none;}
    .topmenu .submenuleft img {display:block;border:#FFF 2px solid;padding:4px;margin-top:5px;}

    .topmenu .subhome .submenuleft a,
    .topmenu .submenu1 .submenuleft a,
    .topmenu .submenu2 .submenuleft a
{
    padding:0px;
    line-height:26px;
    font-size:14px;
background:none;
    display: inline;
    text-align:left;    
    z-index: 0;
color:#FFF;
}
```