# CSS Transition Visibility Not Working for drop down menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, css-transitions

I'm trying to get the menu to delay closing when leaving hover (a forgiveness factor for a 3 level menu). I've put in  a `transition-property: visibility;` and `transition-duration: 2s;` but it isn't doing anything. What am I missing?

If there is a better way to accomplish the forgiveness factor, I'm certainly open to that as well.

[A fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/mseifert/5uy1789s/)

***UPDATE**  I've simplified the example to a 2 layer menu.
There is an [example post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733255/delay-closing-of-submenu-on-a-css-menu-made-exclusively-with-divs) but I'm not sure what the difference is that makes this one work.

The html

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="top"><a class="top_link">Grades</a>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li><a class="fly">Grade 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The css

```
.nav {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  height: 36px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav ul {
  -moz-transition-property: visibility;
  -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-transition-property: visibility;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-property: visibility;
  transition-duration: 2s;
}

.nav li.top {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.nav li a.top_link {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 27px;
  padding: 0 0 0 12px;
}

.nav li:hover {
  position: relative;
}

.nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
}

.nav li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

.nav li:hover ul.sub {
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #3a93d2;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transition effect will only affect the `visibility` property if that is the property that changes between the regular and hover state. Right now you are trying to animate `visibility` but you are showing/hiding the element with `display: none`. Instead of using `display`, change the `visibility` value.

This should work:

```
.nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.nav li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: Thx. I just discovered that when I compared the working link with mine. Makes sense. I wonder what `visibility` of a 3 level menu would do to layout, since `visibility` means the menu still takes up space.

Comment: Strange behavior with the transition to not visible - the sub menu loses its position and color. Any ideas why?

Comment: Looks like it's one of the floats. Odd. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The last section of your CSS `.nav li:hover ul.sub` adds several properties to `ul.sub` but only under the hover state. Those properties go away immediately when the hover stops, but `visibilty` sticks around due to the delay. Change the selector to `.nav li ul.sub` or change your `transition-property` to `all`.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone wants to see the working solution with a gentle fade out in the sub menu, it is below. It takes tweaking to get it to fade only on leaving the hover but immediately showing on the hover.

[In a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mseifert/5uy1789s/)

The html

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="top"><a class="top_link">Grades</a>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li><a class="fly">Grade 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The css

```
.nav {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

.nav ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition-property: visibility, opacity;
  -moz-transition-property: visibility, opacity;
  -webkit-transition-property: visibility, opacity;

  transition-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-transition-function: linear;
  -webkit-transition-function: linear;

  transition-duration: 0s, 0.5s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0s, 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0s, 0.5s;

  transition-delay: 0.5s, 0s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.5s, 0s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s, 0s;
}

.nav li {
  position: relative;
}

.nav li.top {
  float: left;
}

.nav li a.top_link {
  float: left;
  height: 36px;
}

.nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.nav li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition-duration: 0s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;

  transition-delay: 0s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
}

.nav li ul.sub {
  background: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
}
```